# Not money - What or who am I?

Tags: riddle

Here is my first attempt at a riddle. I welcome suggestions for improvement. Here it is:

In most cases, I am purchased and changed by my owners (debatably) adding value to me, then given away for free (in the financial sense, in the usual cases). What am I?

EDIT: I will post the answer in 48 hours or so if needed.

Comment: I think it would be better if you improved the riddle rather than posting the answer because you clearly have some interesting object/thing in mind and it would be disappointing for this idea to go to waste. Expanding the size of the riddle could be an easy way to narrow the amount of possible answers and to compensate for the extra information in the expansion you could carefully reword what you already have to keep the vagueness the same!

Comment: @Adam thank you I will do that in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll echo @MichaelMaggs - this is certainly too broad.

A few things I can think of without particularly trying:

> A business buys cardstock, adds value by printing advertisements/flyers/coupons on it, and gives it away for free to attract clientele.
>
>  Someone buys blank CD-R media, adds value by burning songs on it (mix tape or demo tracks), and gives it away for free to friends, family, love interests, or recording studios.
>
>  More generally, pretty much everyone buys stationery or postcards, changes them by writing on them (and debatably adding informational if not sentimental value), and then gives them away for free to whomever they wanted to send them to.
>
>  Or, even, any of [these gift card holders](https://www.hallmark.com/gift-wrap/gift-card-holders/), which you purchase, add value to by putting a gift card in, and then give away for free as a gift.

Pretty sure you need to narrow this down a lot.  "It's not sufficient that your intended answer fits all parts of the puzzle. If many answers could fit, then the puzzle is under-specified. A well-crafted puzzle will give enough information to rule in the intended solution while ruling out everything else. Also, potential solutions should be testable by referring to *the puzzle*, not by needing a response from the setter as to whether they're right or not. If the puzzle lacks enough specificity to make that determination, then it's probably *too broad*" and likely to be closed as such.

Comment: based on the feedback I received for my question and improvements needed, this is the answer closest to what I had in mind, which is printer paper. Thank you all for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this has multiple valid answers. One would be that you are

> **a pet**.
>  You're usually purchased for money, and changed as you grow adding both monetary and companionship value. But after you die, you're given away free.

Comment: I could see this as a valid answer, however it is not what I am thinking of.

Comment: Hi @ITWorker. A good question here is one that (ideally) has a unique answer. If there are many possible valid answers it becomes an uninteresting game of guessing which of those the questioner had in their mind. You might like to read this question and answer on the Meta site: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6628/should-multiple-answer-questions-be-marked-as-too-broad

Comment: noted for the future!